# Is a continuous map between two topological groups homotopic to a homomorphism between them?

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be two topological groups and $f:G\to H$ be a continuous map.

Is there a continuous homomorphism $g:G\to H$ homotopic to $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not.

If $G,H$ are discrete then this statement is equivalent to whether every function $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism.

Clearly every function $f:G\rightarrow H$ is continuous (because $G$ is discrete).

Moreover if $T:[0,1]\times G \rightarrow H$ is continuous such that $T(0,g) = f(g)$ and $T(1,g) = f'(g)$ then the map $a\mapsto T(a,g)$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ to $H$. As $[0,1]$ is connected and $H$ is discrete this map is necessarily constant and so we must have that $f(g)=f'(g)$ (for every $g\in G$). That means that $f$ is only homotopic to itself!

Thus you can take any two groups, $G,H$ with discrete topology, and any map $f:G\rightarrow H$ that is not a homomorphism. You will get a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there any special condition under which a continuous map homotopic to a homomorphism?

Comment: @M.Ramana I need to think about that. But my answer implies that such a condition must be somehow dependent on the topology of $G$ and $H$. As if the topology is discrete then a continuous map is homotopic to a homomorphism only if it is already a homomorphism. Are you interested in any specific groups?

Comment: Yes you are right. No, I'm working on proof of a general statement on spaces with abelian fundamental group. For this, I thought it's better at first I concentrate on topological groups as an special cases. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have an example with two path-connected groups?

Answer (score 2):

Neat question!

With suitable hypotheses, this question has an affirmative answer. Here is one such answer:

> Let $G$ be a compact connected topological group, and let $H$ be a
> locally compact abelian topological group. Then every continuous
> function $f \colon G \to H$ sending the identity of $G$ to the
> identity of $H$ is homotopic to exactly one continuous
> homomorphism. Moreover, the homotopy can be chosen to preserve the
> identity.

The above statement is Corollary 2 of the following paper of Wladimiro Scheffer:

*Maps between topological groups that are homotopic to homomorphisms*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 33 (1972), 562-567.
https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1972-0301130-8

I'm not sure what other answers to this question might look like (i.e. with different hypotheses on $G$ and $H$), but it's an interesting question.

For example, one cannot drop the assumption that $H$ is abelian, for the homomorphism
$$e^{i\theta} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta}&0\\0&e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}$$
from $S^1$ to $SU(2)$ is at once non-trivial and homotopic (relative to the identity) to the trivial homomorphism since $SU(2) \cong S^3$ is simply connected.

See also:

- Bogatyi, Semeon Antonovich, and Olga Dmitrievna Frolkina. "On commutativity of connected groups." Sbornik: Mathematics 197.1 (2006).
- Rezk, Charles. "Classifying spaces for 1–truncated compact Lie groups." Algebraic & geometric topology 18.1 (2018): 525-546.
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334473/when-does-bg-to-ba-loop-to-a-homomorphism

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's a great statement and it certainly helps my researches a lot.